# $\sin$ as covering map between Riemann surfaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces

$\newcommand\C{\mathbb C} \newcommand\bs{\backslash}$There is a book on Riemann surfaces by Forster that I like very much. I am curious about the first exercise in chapter 1 section 4 on branched and unbranched coverings:

> Let $X:=\C\bs\{\pm1\}$ and $Y:=\C\bs\{(2k+1)\pi/2 : k\in \mathbb Z\}$.
>   Show that $\sin: Y\rightarrow X$ is a topological covering map.
>   Consider the following curves
>   $$u:[0,1]\rightarrow X \qquad t\mapsto 1-e^{2\pi i t}$$ 
>   $$v:[0,1]\rightarrow X \qquad t\mapsto -1+e^{2\pi i t}$$
>
> and let $w_1:[0,1]\rightarrow Y$ be the lifting of $u\cdot v$ with
>   $w_1(0)=0$ and $w_2:[0,1]\rightarrow Y$ be the lifting of $v\cdot u$
>   with $w_2(0)=0$. Show that ($w_1$ and $w_2$ are not "loops") 
>   $w_1(1)=2\pi$ ad $w_2(1)=-2\pi$ (and with this one concludes that the
>   fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ is non-abelian).

I think I am able to do all this, but I think what I get is that $w_1(1)=4\pi$ and $w_2(1)=-4\pi$ (I tried to visualize the whole thing graphically, which is not easy). Is it really the case that $w_1(1)=2\pi$ and $w_2(1)=-2\pi$ or did I just found an error in the book?

Comment: I'd like to mark this as duplicate and close:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148328/liftings-of-curves-u-cdot-v-and-v-cdot-u-with-respect-to-the-sine-covering-m

Comment: Just to add: the reason why I made the mistake was a wrong visualization of the image of sine. Once I saw how the half-plane is mapped from I understood. Here is the Mathematica code to show this: `RegionPlot[Im[Sin[x + I y]]>0, {x,-3Pi,3Pi}, {y,-4,4}, FrameTicks->{Range[-Pi,Pi,Pi/2], Automatic}, PlotPoints->100]`.  And [here](http://bayimg.com/5a030b672a6b184b93b194a6a1d3b4d1dda8880a.jpg) is the output.